# How to remove line numbers from my paper?

Tags: document-classes, line-numbering, journal, mdpi

I am using the template of MDPI

https://www.mdpi.com/data/MDPI_template.zip?v=20201020

I wonder how can I remove line numbers next to each line?

```
%  LaTeX support: latex@mdpi.com 
%  In case you need support, please attach all files that are necessary for compiling as well as the log file, and specify the details of your LaTeX setup (which operating system and LaTeX version / tools you are using).

%=================================================================
\documentclass[journal,article,submit,moreauthors,pdftex]{Definitions/mdpi} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}

% If you would like to post an early version of this manuscript as a preprint, you may use preprint as the journal and change 'submit' to 'accept'. The document class line would be, e.g., \documentclass[preprints,article,accept,moreauthors,pdftex]{mdpi}. This is especially recommended for submission to arXiv, where line numbers should be removed before posting. For preprints.org, the editorial staff will make this change immediately prior to posting.

%--------------------
% Class Options:
%--------------------
%----------
% journal
%----------
% Choose between the following MDPI journals:
% acoustics, actuators, addictions, admsci, adolescents, aerospace, agriculture, agriengineering, agronomy, ai, algorithms, allergies, analytica, animals, antibiotics, antibodies, antioxidants, applmech, applmicrobiol, applnano, applsci, arts, asc, asi, atmosphere, atoms, audiolres, automation, axioms, batteries, bdcc, behavsci, beverages, biochem, bioengineering, biologics, biology, biomechanics, biomedicines, biomedinformatics, biomimetics, biomolecules, biophysica, biosensors, biotech, birds, bloods, brainsci, breath, buildings, businesses, cancers, carbon, cardiogenetics, catalysts, cells, ceramics, challenges, chemengineering, chemistry, chemosensors, chemproc, children, civileng, cleantechnol, climate, clockssleep, cmd, coatings, colloids, compounds, computation, computers, condensedmatter, conservation, constrmater, cosmetics, crops, cryptography, crystals, cyber, dairy, data, dentistry, dermato, dermatopathology, designs, diabetology, diagnostics, digital, disabilities, diseases, diversity, dna, drones, dynamics, earth, ebj, ecologies, econometrics, economies, education, ejbc, ejihpe, electricity, electrochem, electronicmat, electronics, encyclopedia, endocrines, energies, eng, engproc, ent, entropy, environments, environsciproc, epidemiologia, epigenomes, est, fermentation, fibers, fire, fishes, fluids, foods, forecasting, forensicsci, forests, fractalfract, fuels, futureinternet, futureparasites, futurepharmacol, futurephys, galaxies, games, gases, gastroent, gastrointestdisord, gels, genealogy, genes, geographies, geohazards, geomatics, geosciences, geriatrics, hazardousmatters, healthcare, hearts, hemato, heritage, highthroughput, histories, horticulturae, humanities, hydrogen, hydrology, hygiene, idr, ijerph, ijfs, ijgi, ijms, ijns, ijtm, ijtpp, immuno, informatics, information, infrastructures, inorganics, insects, instruments, inventions, iot, j, jcdd, jcm, jcp, jcs, jdb, jfb, jfmk, jimaging, jintelligence, jlpea, jmmp, jmp, jmse, jne, jnt, jof, joitmc, jor, journalmedia, jox, jpm, jrfm, jsan, jtaer, jzbg, kidney, land, languages, laws, life, liquids, literature, livers, logistics, lubricants, machines, macromol, magnetism, magnetochemistry, make, marinedrugs, materials, materproc, mathematics, mca, measurements, medicina, medicines, medsci, membranes, metabolites, metals, micro, microarrays, micromachines, microorganisms, minerals, mining, modelling, molbank, molecules, mps, mti, nanomanufacturing, nanomaterials, ncrna, network, neuroglia, neurolint, neurosci, nitrogen, notspecified, nri, nursrep, nutrients, obesities, oceans, ohbm, oncopathology, optics, oral, organics, osteology, oxygen, parasites, particles, pathogens, pathophysiology, pediatric, pharmaceuticals, pharmaceutics, pharmacy, philosophies, photochem, photonics, physchem, physics, physiolsci, plants, plasma, pollutants, polymers, polysaccharides, preprints, proceedings, processes, prosthesis, proteomes, psych, psychiatryint, publications, quantumrep, quaternary, qubs, radiation, reactions, recycling, regeneration, religions, remotesensing, reports, reprodmed, resources, risks, robotics, safety, sci, scipharm, sensors, separations, sexes, sexes, signals, sinusitis, skins, smartcities, sna, societies, socsci, soilsystems, solids, sports, standards, stats, stresses, surfaces, surgeries, suschem, sustainability, symmetry, systems, taxonomy, technologies, telecom, test, textiles, thermo, tourismhosp, toxics, toxins, transplantology, transportation, traumas, tropicalmed, universe, urbansci, uro, vaccines, vehicles, vetsci, vibration, viruses, vision, water, wem, wevj, women, world

%---------
% article
%---------
% The default type of manuscript is "article", but can be replaced by: 
% abstract, addendum, article, benchmark, book, bookreview, briefreport, casereport, changes, comment, commentary, communication, conceptpaper, conferenceproceedings, correction, conferencereport, expressionofconcern, extendedabstract, meetingreport, creative, datadescriptor, discussion, editorial, essay, erratum, hypothesis, interestingimages, letter, meetingreport, newbookreceived, obituary, opinion, projectreport, reply, retraction, review, perspective, protocol, shortnote, supfile, technicalnote, viewpoint
% supfile = supplementary materials

%----------
% submit
%----------
% The class option "submit" will be changed to "accept" by the Editorial Office when the paper is accepted. This will only make changes to the frontpage (e.g., the logo of the journal will get visible), the headings, and the copyright information. Also, line numbering will be removed. Journal info and pagination for accepted papers will also be assigned by the Editorial Office.

%------------------
% moreauthors
%------------------
% If there is only one author the class option oneauthor should be used. Otherwise use the class option moreauthors.

%---------
% pdftex
%---------
% The option pdftex is for use with pdfLaTeX. If eps figures are used, remove the option pdftex and use LaTeX and dvi2pdf.

%=================================================================
\firstpage{1} 
\makeatletter 
\setcounter{page}{\@firstpage} 
\makeatother
\pubvolume{1}
\issuenum{1}
\articlenumber{0}
\pubyear{2020}
\copyrightyear{2020}
%\externaleditor{Academic Editor: name}
\history{Received: date; Accepted: date; Published: date}

%% MDPI internal command: uncomment if new journal that already uses continuous page numbers 
%\continuouspages{yes}

%------------------------------------------------------------------
% The following line should be uncommented if the LaTeX file is uploaded to arXiv.org
%\pdfoutput=1

%=================================================================
% Add packages and commands here. The following packages are loaded in our class file: fontenc, inputenc, calc, indentfirst, fancyhdr, graphicx,epstopdf, lastpage, ifthen, lineno, float, amsmath, setspace, enumitem, mathpazo, booktabs, titlesec, etoolbox, tabto, xcolor, soul, multirow, microtype, tikz, totcount, amsthm, hyphenat, natbib, hyperref, footmisc, url, geometry, newfloat, caption

%=================================================================
%% Please use the following mathematics environments: Theorem, Lemma, Corollary, Proposition, Characterization, Property, Problem, Example, ExamplesandDefinitions, Hypothesis, Remark, Definition, Notation, Assumption
%% For proofs, please use the proof environment (the amsthm package is loaded by the MDPI class).

%=================================================================
% Full title of the paper (Capitalized)
\Title{Automated ML for EMR analysis: A survey}

% Author Orchid ID: enter ID or remove command
\newcommand{\orcidauthorA}{0000-0000-000-000X} % Add \orcidA{} behind the author's name
%\newcommand{\orcidauthorB}{0000-0000-000-000X} % Add \orcidB{} behind the author's name

% Authors, for the paper (add full first names)
\Author{}


% Authors, for metadata in PDF
\AuthorNames{Firstname Lastname, Firstname Lastname and Firstname Lastname}

% Affiliations / Addresses (Add [1] after \address if there is only one affiliation.)
\address{%
    $^{1}$ \quad 
    $^{2}$ \quad }


% Contact information of the corresponding author
\corres{Correspondence: e-mail@e-mail.com; Tel.: (optional; include country code; if there are multiple corresponding authors, add author initials) +xx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx (F.L.)}

% Current address and/or shared authorship
\firstnote{Current address: Affiliation 3} 
\secondnote{These authors contributed equally to this work.}
% The commands \thirdnote{} till \eighthnote{} are available for further notes

%\simplesumm{} % Simple summary

%\conference{} % An extended version of a conference paper
```

[image]

Comment: If the template for a journal includes those line numbers by default, don't remove them. Chances are your file will be reprocessed by their editors anyways and most likely they created the template in this way to ease their job.

Comment: If after reading @Skillmon's comment, you still want to disable them you can try using `\nolinenumbers` as they seem to be using the `lineno` package.

Comment: Gold Open Access? Maybe you should consider Diamond Open Access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the question. Thanks also to the above comments.
I have solved it.

1. After \begin{document} if you use '\nolinenumbers', then there will be no line numbers throughout the body of the article. However, there will be line numbers in the 'abstract'.
2. To resolve this issue - go to 'mdpi.cls' file and replace all '\linenumbers' by '\nolinenumbers'. I have found three such places. Then compile the main latex file. The problem is solved. You do not need to modify 'mdpi.bst' file.

Answer (score 3):

Reading through the comments in the snippet that you posted, the third option listed is:

```
%----------
% submit
%----------
% The class option "submit" will be changed to "accept" by the Editorial Office when the paper is accepted. This will only make changes to the frontpage (e.g., the logo of the journal will get visible), the headings, and the copyright information. Also, line numbering will be removed. Journal info and pagination for accepted papers will also be assigned by the Editorial Office.
```

A bit off the screen: "Also, line numbering will be removed."